# can't access uploaded files in dist mode in play framework

Tags: playframework-2.2

I have done all mandatory / required steps to run the project in '**dist**' mode,though it is running perfectly,i can't access the files which i've uploaded in the same.
i can see the uploaded files,in '**my_project\bin\public**' folder but not able to download it.
being newbie in play framework i would like to facilitate the users who have uploaded their files in the system to download the same.